# How to play two different videos in two different displays simultaneously using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, raspberry-pi4

I am using

1. Raspberry Pi 4 Model B which has 2 HDMI ports.
2. Gstreamer-1.0

I have two videos saved in memory card. I want to drive two videos to two different HDMI port and play videos in two different Displays simultaneously.
I  would like to know the Gstreamer pipeline to access the HDMI0 and HDMI1 ports and also play two different videos in different displays simultaneously.