# How to play two different videos in two different displays simultaneously using gstreamer?

Tags: video, raspberry-pi3, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, gstreamer-0.10

I am using
1. Raspberry Pi 4 Model B which has 2 HDMI ports.
2. Gstreamer-1.0

I have two videos saved in memory card. I want to drive two videos to two different HDMI port and play videos in two different Displays simultaneously. I would like to know the Gstreamer pipeline to access the HDMI-1 and HDMI-2 ports and also play two different videos in different displays simultaneously.

Here I am trying to drive video.mp4 to HDMI-2.

gst-launch-1.0 playbin3 videosink="mfw-v4lsink device=dev/video18" uri=file:///home/pi/Downloads/video.mp4

I even tried

gst-launch-1.0 playbin3 videosink="mfw-v4lsink device=HDMI-2" uri=file:///home/pi/Downloads/video.mp4

and also

gst-launch-1.0 playbin3 videosink="mfw-v4lsink device=dev/HDMI-2" uri=file:///home/pi/Downloads/video.mp4

I am not able to drive the video to HDMI-2 port.
I expect the video to be played in HDMI-2, but the actual output is coming in HDMI-1 for all the above 3 given pipelines.

Comment: Did you use gst-inspect to get out whats the correct device name of your secondary HDMI port? https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-inspect.html?gi-language=c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play two different videos in two different displays simultaneously using gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865741/how-to-play-two-different-videos-in-two-different-displays-simultaneously-using)

Answer (score 0):

In downloads I have .mkv .mp4 and .avi files. I am trying to drive video to different HDMI port. I have connected two monitors to two hdmi port. 
I used the command modetest. I have only one plane-id. That is 28

I used the following pipeline

**gst-launch-1.0 -vvv -e filesrc location=/home/pi/Downloads/count.mkv ! matroskademux ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec ! kmssink plane-id=28**

and I got the following error

*Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... 
Pipeline is PREROLLING ... 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKMSSink:kmssink0: display-width = 1920 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKMSSink:kmssink0: display-height = 1080 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, level=(string)3, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)0164001effe1001c6764001eacd940b43dbff00080009100000303e90000ea600f162d9601000668ebe3cb22c0, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)8/9, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, interlace-mode=(string)mixed 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, level=(string)3, profile=(string)high, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)8/9, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true 
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/v4l2h264dec:v4l2h264dec0: Device '/dev/video10' does not support interleaved interlacing 
Additional debug info: 
gstv4l2object.c(3817): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/v4l2h264dec:v4l2h264dec0: 
Device wants progressive interlacing 
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll. 
Setting pipeline to NULL ... 
Freeing pipeline ...*

If I use plane-id= 80, I get following error

*Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... 
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause. 
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKMSSink:kmssink0: Could not find a plane for crtc 
Additional debug info: 
gstkmssink.c(755): gst_kms_sink_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKMSSink:kmssink0 
Setting pipeline to NULL ...*

I tried using fbdevsink

**$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! jpegdec ! fbdevsink device=/dev/fb0gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! fbdevsink device=/dev/fb0**

I used this command and it is showing only one frame buffer

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/fb* 
crw-rw---- 1 root video 29, 0 Sep 13 11:10 /dev/fb0**